# Looping and Variable

Tags: java, collatz

I'm taking AP Comp SI A and I'm attempting summer work with no prior coding experience. My assignment is:

> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:
>
> - n → n/2 (n is even)
> - n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
>
> Example: 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
>
> *Note:* every sequence will eventually tend to 1, at which point it is deemed complete.
>
> Find the length of this sequence for each starting value, 1-100, and print them out, next to the starting number.
>
> I.e.
>
> ```
> 1-1
> 2-2
> 3-8
> ```

[image]

Attached is a pictured of what I've tried but I really could use any help you guys could think of. I'm very new to coding so sorry if it's hard to understand. I have seen this same question posted everywhere but none solved by Java and I just cant figure it out.

Comment: This is called a **Collatz sequence** and it's not proven yet whether it actually converges to 1 for **every** starting number – see [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) at Wikipedia.

Comment: Please do NOT post your code as a screen-shot picture. Paste it as a text in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's homework, it's better if the community gives you hints rather than just 'does it' for you.  You'll learn more.  So here's a couple of hints to start with.

(1) Once you have declared a variable type, such as
int lengthNum = 1;  You _don't reuse the 'int' declaration.

Instead just say

lengthNum++

(2) attempt to write a function that takes a number and returns the # of steps to get to one.  Test it with a few low numbers.  Then worry about testing all the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I'll try to write to function like you advised for (2).

Comment: I'm afraid the OP's computer may have RAM too small to test _all_ numbers. Not to mention the time needed... ;-)

Comment: Read a little more carefully (said with a smile, not trying to be mean).  The problem says to test numbers 1 - 100.